# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 13

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After a recent update of Android Studio to version 3.1.2 Build #AI-173.4720617, I can't get the Android Emulator to start. With any AVD, I get the following messages in the Event Log.

> 11:19 AM  Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': Permission denied
>
> 11:19 AM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 13

The first thing I checked is that the folder in question grants me full permission. I exited Android Studio and tried running as Administrator with no luck.

I get the same response if I try to run emulator.exe from the command line (also as Admin).

> ... \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd "Nexus_5X_API_26_x86"
>   Could not launch
>
> 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': Permission denied

So I tried running qemu-system-i386.exe from the command line and I get the following pop-ups.

> The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The message repeats for *Qt5Svg.dll*, *Qt5Core.dll*, and *Qt5Gui.dll*. However, each file can be found in *Android\sdk\emulated\lib* and in *Android\sdk\emulated\lib\qt\lib*.

I tried copying *libwinpthread-1.dll* into the qt\lib folder, and started *qemu-system-i386.exe* from there. I get another popup...

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

I've tried reinstalling Android Studio and the SDK. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the emulator and haxm. I'm running out of ideas.

As for my environment..

- Android Studio 3.1.2
- SDK Build Tools 27.0.3
- Emulator 27.2.9
- SDK Platform-Tools 27.0.1
- SDK Tools 26.1.1
- Windows 10 Enterprise, 64 bit
- 16GB installed memory
- Intel Zeon CPU E3-1270 v5

Please help.